# How python can execute shell command with env

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, `os.system()` can execute shall commands, such as:

```py
os.system("echo $A")
```

It will work well and output value environment variable `A`.

But this seems to not work:

```py
os.system("A=b echo $A")
```

It won't output "b" as expected.

How Python can execute this type of command command?

Comment: "A=b; echo $A" seems to work

Answer (score 0):

> It won't output "b" as expected.

The expansion `$A` to empty string is done by the shell earlier, before running `echo`.

Try this:

```py
os.system("A=b; echo $A")
```